# How do I run Jest test from specific folder only neglecting other folder test?

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a node js project and it have 2 test folders. There are app & admin folder inside of src/**test**/v1. I want script to run test from only app folder. I tried using `jest app`, `jest app --testPathPattern=src/__test__/v1/app"`but both didn't worked.

Comment: Run npm run test from the main folder - test files would be picked up automatically

Comment: from the main folder means?

Comment: From the root folder

Comment: Assuming jest task is a task run via npm

Answer (score 3):

By default jest will try to run all tests recursively of the root directory (where package.json is)

To specify a specific folder via CLI :

```
jest --testPathPattern=src/test/v1/app
```

You can also setup package.json to have specific test commands for running tests for specific folders:

```
"scripts": {
   "test:app": "jest --testPathPattern=src/test/v1/app",
   "test:admin": "jest --testPathPattern=src/test/v1/admin",
},
```